# scala - quickly construct the hex represented control chars in a string

Tags: scala

I have a string sequence from the output of an application which prints the control chars in "\x00" method. Example

```
\x00R50\x00\x00\x00\x01
```

I'm converting this to a scala string in REPL by inspecting the char one at a time and adding to a byte array.

```
scala> val ar:Array[Byte]=Array(0,82,53,48,0,0,1)
ar: Array[Byte] = Array(0, 82, 53, 48, 0, 0, 1)

scala> val a = ar.map(_.toChar).mkString
a: String = ?R50???

scala>
```

This seems to be laborious.. is there a quick way to convert `\x00R50\x00\x00\x00\x01` to the `val a` as above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java or Scala. How to convert characters like \x22 into String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47032049/java-or-scala-how-to-convert-characters-like-x22-into-string)

Comment: Did you check `new String(Array(0,82,53,48,0,0,1))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input `String` only needs to be traversed once, but each `Match` goes through a few transitions.

```
val str = raw"\x00R50\x00\x00\x00\x01"

raw"\\x([0-9a-fA-F]{2})".r.replaceAllIn(str, m =>
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(m.group(1),16).toChar.toString)
//res0: String = ?R50????
```

The value of each control char is preserved.

Comment: sometimes it can be hex also.. from A-F... i.e non-printable characters

Answer (score 4):

There is the constructor in `java.lang.String` :

```
public String(byte bytes[])
```

```
scala> new String(Array[Byte](0, 82, 53, 48, 0, 0, 1))
res0: String = ?R50???
```